# How do I remove the class on all siblings?

Tags: jquery-ui

I've got:

```
<th>First Name<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"></span></th>
```

When the user clicks on a th cell, I need to clear the span tag from every one of it's siblings.

```
$('th').click(function() {
var $th = $(this);
$th.siblings().each
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear -- your title says remove the class, but your post says you need to clear the span tag? To remove the class you would use `removeClass()` in your `each` block. Otherwise to remove the entire tag you could use `remove()`.

**Edit**
You could try this:

```
$('th').click(function() {
  var $th = $(this);
  $th.siblings().each(function() {
    $('span').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: You missed a closing ) for the each method.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I believe you could also do something like this, without having to use the `each` function: `$th.siblings().remove('span');`. Not sure, but give it a try.